# How to add prometheus end-point to spring boot application using micrometer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I want to gather metrics from my spring boot application with prometheus.

I added this to my pom.xml:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.micrometer/micrometer-registry-prometheus -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also present is spring-boot-starter-actuator.

I also tried adding prometheus to the properties file:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=prometheus, *
```

I get a 404 error on accessing /actuator/prometheus (/actuator works)

As a side note, I don't know how to call "mvn" to get a dependency tree, "mvn" is not in the path. I have seen some dependencies being downloaded after I edited pom.xml.

I also have no clue what the "scope: runtime" parameter does and would like to know.

Comment: It works now after restarting the browser and the IDE in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in spring boot 3

```
management:
  server:
    port: 8081

  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,prometheus
  prometheus:
    metrics:
      export:
        enabled: true
```

Comment: @moken What is unclear exactly ?

Comment: This answer directly answers for the question "How to add prometheus end-point to spring boot application using micrometer?"

Comment: @moken if you have any question - I am ready to help. What is unclear exactly ?